# ACF Moving Repeater Subfield Values to Field in Post

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Custom Post Type with a repeater field with 5 subfields. I need to rebuild these posts so that the subfields are normal fields without copying and pasting. They both the repeater and fields are showing in the post and have the same names.

Is there a way of going this? I have 60 odd posts on 8 different websites that need updating so something a little more automated will be ideal.

Thanks in advance,
Paddy

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking? Any code?

Answer (score 0):

So I worked this out but editing the database. This link really helped [ACF Moving Fields](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/moving-fields-from-one-group-to-another/)

I downloaded the database, found my repeater field speakers_0_fieldname and did a find and replace to remove the repeater part; speaker_0_ which just left me with the single field name.